# Can my app be notified when a session is destroyed? If so, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise, warden

My Devise/Warden-based app stores a model ID in the session[] variable.  I want destroy the object when the session[] is destroyed.

- Is there a callback or some mechanism to notify my app when the session is destroyed?
- Is the mechanism dependable, or should I run a nightly cleanup script to vacuum up any orphaned objects?

To make it clear, here's a snippet of my controller code:

```
class WizardsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_or_create_wizard
  ...
private

  def find_or_create_wizard
    @wizard = Wizard.find_by_id(session[:wizard_id]) || Wizard.create.tap {|w| session[:wizard_id] = w }
  end

end
```

To restate the question: how and when should I destroy the Wizard object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts| 
  # callback 
end
```

Use the Warden::Hooks https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/hooks.rb to do things after sign out or authentication.

Comment: As one famous Larry used to say, "poifect"!

Answer (score 0):

By session, do you mean when the user logs out?

Try monkey patching the `sign_out` method in your `application_controller.rb`
You can find the relevant Gem code in `lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb`

```
def sign_out(resource_or_scope=nil)
    Wizard.find_by_id(session[:wizard_id]) || Wizard.create.tap {|w| session[:wizard_id] = w }
    super(resource_or_scope)
end
```

Session data is also cleared whenever a user signs in or signs up via a function called `expire_session_data_after_sign_in!`, could override that too:

```
def expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        Wizard.find_by_id(session[:wizard_id]) || Wizard.create.tap {|w| session[:wizard_id] = w }
        super
end
```

Comment: By 'session', I mean whatever mechanism I need to avoid leaking Wizard objects over time: I create a singleton Wizard object in the current session, I simply want to know when to delete it.  I suppose your solution would work, but I'm hoping to find a technique that doesn't require patching the system.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a built-in callback for sign_out actions (I have not pulled the very latest source). All of my Devise tweaks involve Monkey Patching. It's nothing out of the ordinary for Ruby. If you are very worried about it, you could setup a Delayed Job to do this for you. I'd probably just use DJ.